# What to do when an edit forms an totally different question which is a good question at all anyway?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I asked this question: [What's the distinction between "planetary formation mechanisms" and "gravitational collapse"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16147/10102)
And it got edited when I had not that much time to check the content. 
Now when I checked it, I noticed that the edit made my question ask for something completly different as I was interested in, forming a diferent question.
While "both" questions received upvotes and I'm also pretty much interested in answers about the past edit question, I'm not sure how to preceed.

Should I let the OP as it is now and just repost my original question again?
Or should I rollback and ask the past edit question seperately?

While tending to option 2, just while writing the post received a past edit related answer (as far I can tell), Making it even harder to decide what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still early. Since you are the OP and the question was edited in a way that changed the question you were asking, you should roll it back. If someone wants to ask the question it was changed to, they can do so separately. When edits occur by low rep users, this is one of the things that reviewers check for--to make sure that edits don't alter the actual question beyond the author's intent. Unfortunately, there are sometimes cases where high rep user edits that don't get reviewed may cause this, and it can get overlooked. Thanks for catching it early on!

Comment: Also, you may want to notify Rob Jeffries that you rolled back edits, assuming his answer doesn't answer your original question.

Comment: This is a pretty odd thing, that never ever should happen. I'm still receiving Answers on the old title while I allready yesterday rolled it back. And since I'm a none-professionell in this topic, its even pretty hard for me to distingush if the answer is just in the wrong place, or I'm not understanding theirs. How can I handle this?

Comment: @Zaibis Actually, the new answer on your question looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Then thx for you input. But you see: it is doing alot of confusion especially if one isn't pro in the topic. :)